# I have some problems with PDO and Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, string, pdo, foreach

I'm not a native guy so I'm sorry for those mistakes.

I'm using PDO, and welp, I need to take the column's names of the one table.

```
$testing = $this->connection->query(" SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'niveles' ");
```

Okay, that was kind of easy.

The problem it gave me a all them, and I don't need the first two strings.

It's giving me the next strings.

```
> ID USER NIVEL_1 NIVEL_2 NIVEL_3
```

and this is what I'd like to get.

```
> NIVEL_1 NIVEL_2 NIVEL_3
```

I tried with array_slice in a forearch.

```
foreach (array_slice($testing, 2) as $levels) {
          echo $levels[0] . ' ';
```

But it doesn't work like I'd like to.

I tried also with this one.

```
  foreach ($testing as $levels) {
      if($levels[0] != "ID" and $levels[0] != "USER"){
      echo $levels[0] . ' ';}}
```

and it works fine for me, but I'm sure is not the best way.

Thank you all...!

Comment: `... AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ('ID', 'USER')`. In any case, attempting to slice the array by numeric indices means nothing if the results aren't ordered

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot! @Phil :)

Comment: Sorry bothered you once again, @Phil I was wondering how could I do the same stuff in this query.

query("SELECT * FROM NIVELES WHERE USER ='$user' ");

Taking all except ID/user. It's planned to add columns in the future, so there's no sense make a query with the column's name. 

Thank you :)

Comment: "adding columns in the future" is a clear sign of a failed database design. A table should never have numbered columns and should pretty much never be extended.